# JsonParser ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when parsing json

Tags: java, json, parsing

The following code should work as a JsonParser but it is returning an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even though I check that there are still elements to parse.

```
 public void parseJson(String url) {
     try {
         InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
         JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(is);
         while (parser.hasNext()) {
             Event e = parser.next();
             if (e == Event.KEY_NAME) {
                 if (parser.getString().equals("name") && parser.hasNext()) {
                     parser.next();
                     writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("names.txt"));
                     writer.write(parser.getString());
                 }
             }
         }
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
 }
```

The error produced is such:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readChar(JsonTokenizer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.read(JsonTokenizer.java:98)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readString(JsonTokenizer.java:124)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:310)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.nextToken(JsonParserImpl.java:157)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:182)
at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:150)
at proj.Proj2.parseJson(Proj2.java:43)
at proj.Proj1.main(Proj1.java:78)
```

It parses everything up to when the error is thrown.

Sample JSON that produces error:

```
[{"id":774,"na":"Hungry Leaf","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1200,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"2608 Erwin Rd, Durham, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2608 Erwin Rd","addr2":"","city":"Durham","state":"NC","postal_code":"27705-3843"},"city":"Durham","latitude":36.008621,"longitude":-78.94474,"del":1200,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":780,"na":"Armadillo Grill","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Mexican","Tex-Mex"],"addr":"439 Glenwood Ave, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"439 Glenwood Ave","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27603-1219"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.785754,"longitude":-78.647293,"del":1080,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":783,"na":"Chef Mario's Bistro","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":2880,"mino":150,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Sandwiches"],"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27607-3060"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.818683,"longitude":-78.692145,"del":2880,"mino":150,"is_delivering":0},{"id":784,"na":"Chef Mario's Catering","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":4320,"mino":150,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Catering","Italian","Sandwiches"],"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27607-3060"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.818683,"longitude":-78.692145,"del":4320,"mino":150,"is_delivering":0},{"id":786,"na":"D'Nardys Caterers","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1320,"mino":6.55,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Catering","Italian","Sandwiches"],"addr":"314 Madison Grove Pl, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"314 Madison Grove Pl","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27519-8161"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.82135,"longitude":-78.854469,"del":1320,"mino":6.55,"is_delivering":0},{"id":787,"na":"Danny's Bar-B-Que","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":2640,"mino":100,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Barbecue"],"addr":"9561 Chapel Hill Rd, Morrisville, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"9561 Chapel Hill Rd","addr2":"","city":"Morrisville","state":"NC","postal_code":"27560-7359"},"city":"Morrisville","latitude":35.805972,"longitude":-78.809315,"del":2640,"mino":100,"is_delivering":1},{"id":792,"na":"Flying Biscuit","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1440,"mino":150,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"2016 Clark Ave, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2016 Clark Ave","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27605-1604"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.788996,"longitude":-78.659642,"del":1440,"mino":150,"is_delivering":1},{"id":793,"na":"Gateway Restaurant","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1320,"mino":50,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast"],"addr":"2411 Crabtree Blvd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2411 Crabtree Blvd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27604-2232"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.805222,"longitude":-78.611873,"del":1320,"mino":50,"is_delivering":0},{"id":796,"na":"Hibachi Xpress","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":720,"mino":150,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"addr":"2470 Walnut St, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2470 Walnut St","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27518-9212"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.75113,"longitude":-78.741205,"del":720,"mino":150,"is_delivering":0},{"id":798,"na":"HoneyBaked Ham","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":60,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Sandwiches"],"addr":"5275 Six Forks Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"5275 Six Forks Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27609-4431"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.85326,"longitude":-78.642593,"del":1080,"mino":60,"is_delivering":0},{"id":804,"na":"Moe's Southwest Grill","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Mexican","Tex-Mex"],"addr":"506 Daniels St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"506 Daniels St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27605-1317"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.791061,"longitude":-78.66118,"del":1080,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":806,"na":"Ole Time Barbecue","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":75,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Barbecue"],"addr":"6309 Hillsborough St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"6309 Hillsborough St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27606-1148"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.787922,"longitude":-78.73851,"del":1080,"mino":75,"is_delivering":0},{"id":811,"na":"The Q Shack","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":180,"mino":40,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Barbecue"],"addr":"North Hills, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"North Hills","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27609"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.837521,"longitude":-78.64312,"del":180,"mino":40,"is_delivering":0},{"id":812,"na":"We Cook For You","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":720,"mino":125,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Caribbean","Catering","Sandwiches"],"addr":"1125 Fuller St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"1125 Fuller St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27603-2217"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.765381,"longitude":-78.650581,"del":720,"mino":125,"is_delivering":0},{"id":813,"na":"WhichWich Superior Sandwiches","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":75,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Sandwiches"],"addr":"4025 Lake Boone Trl, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"4025 Lake Boone Trl","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27607-2928"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.815604,"longitude":-78.696541,"del":1080,"mino":75,"is_delivering":0},{"id":820,"na":"Greens","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1080,"mino":6.55,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Italian","Seafood"],"addr":"4120 Main at North Hills St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"4120 Main at North Hills St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27609-5754"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.837546,"longitude":-78.642515,"del":1080,"mino":6.55,"is_delivering":0},{"id":861,"na":"Catering By Design","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":240,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Catering","Italian","Pizza","Sandwiches"],"addr":"132 Kilmayne Dr, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"132 Kilmayne Dr","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27511-4465"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.769451,"longitude":-78.783912,"del":240,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":3498,"na":"Z Pizza","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":900,"mino":75,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Pizza","Sandwiches"],"addr":"421 Fayetteville St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"421 Fayetteville St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27601-1778"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.77467,"longitude":-78.639389,"del":900,"mino":75,"is_delivering":0},{"id":3500,"na":"Artisan Sandwiches & Salads","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":900,"mino":50,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"421 Fayetteville St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"421 Fayetteville St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27601-1778"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.77467,"longitude":-78.639389,"del":900,"mino":50,"is_delivering":0},{"id":3795,"na":"Chef Mario's Catering Dinner","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":4320,"mino":150,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Asian","Barbecue","Breakfast","Catering","Italian","Jamaican","Mediterranean","Sandwiches","Seafood","Thai"],"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2610 Wycliff Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27607-3060"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.818683,"longitude":-78.692145,"del":4320,"mino":150,"is_delivering":0},{"id":3895,"na":"A Catered Affair","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":720,"mino":125,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Asian","Breakfast","Catering","Italian","Jamaican","Sandwiches"],"addr":"1125 Fuller St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"1125 Fuller St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27603-2217"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.765381,"longitude":-78.650581,"del":720,"mino":125,"is_delivering":0},{"id":4011,"na":"Neomonde Mediterranean","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1260,"mino":125,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Breakfast","Mediterranean","Sandwiches"],"addr":"9650 Strickland Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"9650 Strickland Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27615-1937"},"city":"Raleigh","del":1260,"mino":125,"is_delivering":0},{"id":4425,"na":"Dorry's Downtown Deli","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1320,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"211 E Chatham St, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"211 E Chatham St","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27511-3427"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.787534,"longitude":-78.777666,"del":1320,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":4427,"na":"Pogo","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":180,"mino":40,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"201 E Hargett St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"201 E Hargett St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27601-1437"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.778141,"longitude":-78.635834,"del":180,"mino":40,"is_delivering":0},{"id":4428,"na":"Chick-fil-A","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1200,"mino":200,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Sandwiches"],"addr":"1803 N Harrison Ave, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"1803 N Harrison Ave","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27513-2408"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.828831,"longitude":-78.769402,"del":1200,"mino":200,"is_delivering":0},{"id":6142,"na":"Spartacus Restaurant","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1200,"mino":300,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Mediterranean","Sandwiches"],"addr":"4139 Old Chapel Hill Rd, Durham, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"4139 Old Chapel Hill Rd","addr2":"","city":"Durham","state":"NC","postal_code":"27707-5057"},"city":"Durham","del":1200,"mino":300,"is_delivering":0},{"id":7776,"na":"Firehouse Subs","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":120,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"1539 Us Highway 70 E, Garner, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"1539 Us Highway 70 E","addr2":"","city":"Garner","state":"NC","postal_code":"27529"},"city":"Garner","del":120,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":7985,"na":"Ben & Jerry's Ice Cream","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":2880,"mino":200,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Bakery","Ice Cream"],"addr":"102 W Franklin St, Chapel Hill, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"102 W Franklin St","addr2":"","city":"Chapel Hill","state":"NC","postal_code":"27516-2516"},"city":"Chapel Hill","latitude":35.91304,"longitude":-79.056091,"del":2880,"mino":200,"is_delivering":1},{"id":10509,"na":"Catering By Design - Dinner","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":240,"mino":6.55,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Catering","Italian","Sandwiches","Seafood"],"addr":"132 Kilmayne Dr, Cary, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"132 Kilmayne Dr","addr2":"","city":"Cary","state":"NC","postal_code":"27511-4465"},"city":"Cary","latitude":35.769451,"longitude":-78.783912,"del":240,"mino":6.55,"is_delivering":1},{"id":12715,"na":"Top This Cafe @ The Atrium","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":45,"mino":0,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Breakfast","Sandwiches"],"addr":"2501 Blue Ridge Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"2501 Blue Ridge Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27607-6436"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.814449,"longitude":-78.705399,"del":45,"mino":0,"is_delivering":0},{"id":12724,"na":"Donovan's Dish","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1200,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Catering","Sandwiches"],"addr":"1040 Buck Jones Rd, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"1040 Buck Jones Rd","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27606-3323"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.770224,"longitude":-78.739941,"del":1200,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":12739,"na":"Lubrano's Ristorante Italiano","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1200,"mino":125,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Italian"],"addr":"101 Keybridge Dr, Morrisville, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"101 Keybridge Dr","addr2":"","city":"Morrisville","state":"NC","postal_code":"27560-5911"},"city":"Morrisville","latitude":35.819771,"longitude":-78.822189,"del":1200,"mino":125,"is_delivering":1},{"id":23709,"na":"DeMarco's Restaurant & Bar","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":1260,"mino":125,"can":1}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Italian"],"addr":"3607 Falls River Ave, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"3607 Falls River Ave","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27614-7359"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.930141,"longitude":-78.564522,"del":1260,"mino":125,"is_delivering":1},{"id":23710,"na":"Green Planet Catering","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":4200,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Catering","Sandwiches"],"addr":"218 S Blount St, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"218 S Blount St","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27601-1408"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.777495,"longitude":-78.63662,"del":4200,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":23815,"na":"Capital Center Catering","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":960,"mino":150,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Bakery","Catering","Italian","Sandwiches"],"addr":"217 E Main St, Clayton, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"217 E Main St","addr2":"","city":"Clayton","state":"NC","postal_code":"27520-2449"},"city":"Clayton","latitude":35.652088,"longitude":-78.458515,"del":960,"mino":150,"is_delivering":0},{"id":23817,"na":"Firewurst","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":960,"mino":100,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["American","Sandwiches"],"addr":"8531 Brier Creek Pky, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"8531 Brier Creek Pky","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27617-7333"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.905433,"longitude":-78.786068,"del":960,"mino":100,"is_delivering":0},{"id":32244,"na":"Don Rio's Southwest Catering","cs_phone":"919-234-7755","rds_info":{"id":125,"name":"Triangle Food Guy","logo":""},"services":{"deliver":{"time":720,"mino":125,"can":0}},"allow_tip":1,"allow_asap":1,"cu":["Mexican","Tex-Mex"],"addr":"3607 Falls River Ave, Raleigh, NC","full_addr":{"addr":"3607 Falls River Ave","addr2":"","city":"Raleigh","state":"NC","postal_code":"27614-7359"},"city":"Raleigh","latitude":35.930141,"longitude":-78.564522,"del":720,"mino":125,"is_delivering":0}]
```

Comment: Well, give us a sample of your JSON that would reproduce this error.

Comment: Your code and that json works for me.

Comment: Hmm strange. That's a shorter version of the JSON I'm using but this works and my complete JSON file doesn't.

Comment: Which version of the JSON library are you using?

Comment: org.glassfish version 1.0.1. Looks like it throws the error when the JSON files become too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [this was a bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JSONP-15?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) in version 1.0.1. [Here's another thread](https://java.net/projects/jsonp/lists/issues/archive/2013-07/message/5) that talks about it. The `JsonTokenizer` class has changed pretty dramatically since then. Upgrade to 1.0.2 and you will be fine.